# Nginx rewrite sends traffic to IP address, not URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx set up as a reverse proxy for a docker microservice. There's a location block that rewrites the url from `/wrong` to `/right`:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name example.com;

        location /right {
            proxy_pass http://microservice_servers;
        }

        location /wrong {
            rewrite ^/wrong/(\w+) /right/$1 redirect;
        }
    }
```

What this is intended to do is rewrite the url from `https://example.com/wrong/otherstuff` to `https://example.com/right/otherstuff`.
What actually happens though, is that it rewrites to `http://<ip_address>/right/otherstuff`.

(One possible complicating factor is that I don't have control of the certs for this site. Those are controlled by the client, who puts them on an app gateway in front of our server. So my nginx config only handles http traffic at port 80, no https from 443. I'm not sure if that's actually relevant, but just in case, there it is.)

I've tried an assortment of changes to the rewrite block, including adding `$server_name`, changing the flag to `last` (returns the right content but doesn't change the url), and changing the flag to `break` (which does not return the expected content).

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The title says "rewrite", but the rule is a redirect?

Comment: It uses the `rewrite` directive with a `redirect` flag: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: So, following the documentation, the URL received is changed, put in a 302, and sent back to the client (which is the app gateway handling HTTPS)? And presumably that app gateway processes the 302, and sends the new URL back to NGINX? Because that's how you end up in `/right`. The `rewrite` itself doesn't cause NGINX to restart at `/right` internally. You might want to wireshark the messages exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your `rewrite...redirect` statement will generate a 302 response with the full URL specified in an HTTP Location response header.

You can confirm this using `curl -I https://example.com/wrong/otherstuff`.

Nginx fills in the protocol and domain name, based on the original request. This `server` block receives requests over `http` and we can infer from your question that the Host header uses its IP address.

You either need to specify the full URL in the `rewrite` statement:

```
rewrite ^/wrong/(\w+) https://example.com/right/$1 redirect;
```

Alternatively, use relative URLs:

```
absolute_redirect off;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect) for details.